# Mock an object which is part of mocked object

Tags: spring, mockito, testng

when I run the test case I get AnObj mocked. this is used from inside the target classes method. when that method gets invoked the 'anOtherObj' is accessed and that is found to be null. Can some one please point out how to make sure 'anOtherObj' is not null so that I dont get nullpointer there?

```
    @Test
    public class TestTargetTest {

    @Mock
    private AnObj anObj;

    @InjectMocks
    private TestTarget testTarget;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testTarget() {

        when(anObj.someMethod()).thenCallRealMethod();

        testTarget.testTarget();



    }

}

@Component
public class TestTarget {

    @Autowired
    private AnObj anObj;

    public void testTarget(){

        anObj.someMethod();
    }
}

@Component
public class AnObj {

    @Autowired
    private AnOtherObj anOtherObj;

    public void someMethod(){
        syso(anOtherObj.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `mirrorIbpCusUserRepository`?

Comment: that would have ensured that "anOtherObj.toString()" was successfully called.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize annotated mocks in your test class.

```
@BeforeMethod
public void beforeClass() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out ... but the problem was deeper than missing this. This function I had in the actual  class but failed to post here for brevity. I 'm posting the answer now. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Why would you care what's inside mock (AnObj)? I assume you haven't yet declared interactions on that mock using Mockito.when.

Comment: you are right when we talk about AnObj.someMethod(). I will either mock this method or call real one. I call real one. And when real method gets called that accesses the class member.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Valya that point was valid. I shouldn't have mocked that. I needed to autowire 'AnObj'. Thanks a lot for all the help. It made the difference.